# EhCache Exception on startup when using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, ehcache

I was trying to use EhCache with Apache Camel using Sprin Boot. While it works as expected. there is an exception on startup. It does not cause any issues in the functionality I guess (according to my test, everything works as expected). But is there any way to avoid that exception?

```
2020-09-28 23:46:38,397 [main][DEBUG] org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheManagerFactory - Turning off EHCache update checker ...
2020-09-28 23:46:38,400 [main][WARN ] org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheManagerFactory - Error turning off EHCache update checker. Beware information sent over the internet!
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: updateCheck
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2411)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheManagerFactory.getInstance(CacheManagerFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheEndpoint.initializeCache(CacheEndpoint.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cache.CacheProducer.doStart(CacheProducer.java:45)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DeferServiceStartupListener.onCamelContextStarted(DeferServiceStartupListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3868)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3647)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3488)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3247)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$4.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3243)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3266)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3243)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3159)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:133)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.sreejesh.CamelCacheMainClass.main(CamelCacheMainClass.java:12)
2020-09-28 23:46:39,400 [main][DEBUG] net.sf.ehcache.Cache - No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
2020-09-28 23:46:39,403 [main][DEBUG] net.sf.ehcache.Cache - CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
```

My EhCache Configuration XML:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    
    <cache name="cache1"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

I have tried to set the updateCheck as false, no luck. I even tried to remove the updateCheck field itself from the XML, even that did not help (though it started fine with the same exception).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You did not post your camel code to at least add additional context to your question.